# How to write and read ndarray to pyarrow plasma store?

Tags: pyarrow

I'm trying to write an ndarray into pyarrow plasma store and read it in another process.
I've googled but I wasn't able find a similar snipped code.

- The ndrarray is an RGB video frame.

To write to the store I do:

```py
buffer_id = plasma.ObjectID.from_random()
tensor = pa.Tensor.from_numpy(frame)
data_size = pa.get_tensor_size(tensor)
buf = plasma_client.create(buffer_id, data_size)
array = np.frombuffer(buf).reshape(frame.shape)
array[:] = frame
plasma_client.seal(buffer_id)
```

and to read I do:

```
for object_id in  plasma_client.list():
    [buff] = plasma_client.get_buffers([object_id])
    reader = pa.BufferReader(buff)
    tensor2 = pa.read_tensor(reader)
    frame = tensor2.to_numpy()
    process_frame(frame)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writer.py", line 68, in write_to_plasma
    array = np.frombuffer(buf).reshape(frame.shape)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1154768 into shape (1458,2112,3)
```

Am I missing something here for the data format, do I need to reshape the image manually?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html#storing-arrow-objects-in-plasma), you should write the pyarrow Tensor directly into the buffer:

```py
import pyarrow.ipc as ipc

buffer_id = plasma.ObjectID.from_random()
tensor = pa.Tensor.from_numpy(frame)
data_size = ipc.get_tensor_size(tensor)
buf = plasma_client.create(buffer_id, data_size)
stream = pa.FixedSizeBufferWriter(buf)
ipc.write_tensor(tensor, stream)
plasma_client.seal(buffer_id)
```

Looking at your code, this part doesn't make sense:

```
array = np.frombuffer(buf).reshape(frame.shape)
```

I don't think you can read/write the numpy array directly form the buffer given arrow adds some metada to it.

You can get the tensor back this way:

```
[buf2] = plasma_client.get_buffers([buffer_id])
reader = pa.BufferReader(buf2)
tensor2 = pa.ipc.read_tensor(reader)
```